# Deny access to ROLE_ADMIN symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I work with with Symfony 2.7 and FOSUserBundle 2.0

What i want is to allow access to /admin to `ROLE_ADMIN` user but to deny him other paths.

```
# app/security.yml

access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:      ROLE_ADMIN
```

I thought about `php app/console fos:user:demote admin ROLE_USER` but `ROLE_USER` is the default role of FOSUser, so every times the admin connects, `ROLE_USER` comes back in addition to `ROLE_ADMIN`.

How can do this ?

Comment: Make another role and add it to all users except admin.

Comment: Yes, that seems pretty logic. How can i do this please? Any link? Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, `ROLE_ADMIN` as no access to `ROLE_MANAGER`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/roles: ROLE_MANAGER }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:       
        - ROLE_USER
    ROLE_MANAGER:    
        - ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:     
        - ROLE_ADMIN
```